# Invalid escape sequence \d

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check if a password contain at least one lower case letter, one upper case letter, one digit and one special character.

i'm trying this:

```
if(!password.matches("(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=])")){
        username = "Error";
    }
```

but give me an error saying: invalid escape sequence.

Someone can help me to solve the problem and can confirm that is a correct pattern?

Thanks, whit \\d don't do error but it don't match with a string like Paul%88 why?

Comment: try replacing **\d** with **\\d**

Comment: Did you try replacing \d with \\d?  (late on the trigger again!)

Comment: I would recommend carefully testing each of those special characters. They may have special meaning in regex and may need to be escaped.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Java will treat `\` inside a string as starting an [escape sequence](https://web.archive.org/web/20110825073447/http://ehis.ebscohost.com.mms02.cerritos.edu/jwilson/java_language_resources/Java_Escape_Sequences.htm). Make sure you use `\\` instead (so that you get an actual `\` character in the string) and you should be ok.

**Quick Update**: As Etienne points out, if you actually want a `\` in the RegEx itself, you'll need to use `\\\\`, since that will produce `\\` in the string, which will produce `\` in the RegEx.

**New Question Update:** You mention that your RegEx doesn't work, and I'm pretty sure that's because it's wrong. If you just want to ensure one of each type of character class is present, you may just want to create one RegEx for each class, and then check the password against each one. Passwords are pretty much guaranteed to be short (and you can actually control that yourself) so the perf hit should be minimal.

Comment: In fact, for any escape sequence in a Java regexp, they actually mean double backslashes so that Java can replace them with a single backslash, then the regexp parser can replace the backslash and its following character with whatever it's supposed to represent.

Comment: And this means that, to actually get the \ character in a Java regex, you have to write \\\\.

Comment: now don't give an error but don't match a string like Paul%88

Comment: This site helped me so much with this. You actually get a Java string from the regex you submit. http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 2):

I used this to quickly test it: http://www.regexplanet.com/simple/index.html

Looks like it works if you put .* at the end. I guess you need to actually include a non-look-ahead regex as well.

Here is the entire regex:

```
(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&+=]).*
```

Of course in your java code you must escape the backslash as mentioned already.

Comment: Doesn't this match because none of the capture groups match, but then the `.*` at the end says "match anything"?

Comment: No. I tested it and it properly requires all those characters before matching. I think if you don't include any non-look-around groups then it's as if you supplied a blank regex and if your string is anything but blank it won't match.

Comment: You're right. I tested a string I thought shouldn't match but did; in reality, it should have matched.